# Using async.js to Perform Asynchronous Actions In Loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, coffeescript, async.js

I know I'm going to post this and then get it working, not to mention the title but...

I'm in a situation where I need to do some async code to each element in an array that I'm given, and then do some checks after all of them have finished.  Normally, if I would use async.js here, however the way I'm doing it isn't getting my the results I want.

So this is my logic, I figure I can create an array of functions, however the way I'm doing this seems to have async.js returning me a list of functions in the result.

```
findLeadThatCanBeTaken : (leads, user, manualTake, cb) =>
  if(leads.length == 0) then return cb(null, null)

  funcArr = []
  self = this

  for lead in leads
    fun = (callback) ->
      console.log(lead.state)
      State.get lead.state, (e, state) ->
        if !state or state.canBeCalled(self.currentTime())
          return callback(null, lead._id.toString)

        return callback(null, null)

    funcArr.push(fun)

  async.parallel funcArr, (e, r) ->
    if (e)
      return cb(message:'No leads can be called at the current time', null)

    id = _.compact(r)
    id = r[0] if r.length

    if (!id || !id.length)
      return cb(message:'No leads can be called at the current time', null)

    lead = _.filter leads, (l) -> return l._id.toString() == id

    # Code handling 
    @takeLead(lead, user, cb)
```

I'm 90% sure the issue is this array I am creating isn't being assigned like I think it is, but I'm not sure.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you have a classic "closure inside a loop" problem:

```
for lead in leads
  fun = (callback) ->
    # some stuff that uses 'lead'...
```

The problem is that all your `fun` functions will have a reference to exactly the same `lead` and when those functions execute, `lead` will refer to the last value it had in the loop.

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) (bottom of that section):

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

Sound familiar? You probably want to get the value of `lead` on each iteration rather than just dragging around `lead` itself with something like this:

```
for lead in leads
  do (lead) ->
    fun = (callback) ->
      # What you have now...
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long, I was playing with using `do()` but it wasn't working.  Ends up, it was how I was pushing the function to that array, I was using something different than above at the time.  Ends up this was the issue!